# Css navigation bar hovering

Tags: html, css

Trying to make a site with html, and I have a navigation bar at the top of the screen, want it to have a hover effect.

```css
.topnav {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}
.topnav a {
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
  color: white;
}
.topnav a:hover {
  background-color:green;
}
```

```html
<div class="topnav">
  <a class="active" href="#" onclick=replace('Home')>Home</a>
  <a href="#" onclick=replace('News')>News</a>
  <a href="#" onclick=replace('Contact')>Contact</a>
  <a href="#" onclick=replace('About')>About</a>
</div>
```

<sub>Note that the replace() function does nothing as of now</sub>

I tried to use AI to find a solution and have not found any.

In this case, I want the home button to have the green bg, then whenever any other button is hovered over the green bg of the home button goes away, and the button that was hovered over gets the green bg. Also if the home button gets hovered over it needs to still have a green bg

As of now I have not found a fix on stackoverflow, note that I might be wrong.

Comment: Do you need this to be in pure CSS? if so, I am not sure if there is a way, but with some javascript I should be able to get something working.

Comment: It does not need to be pure css, it more of just needs to work.

Answer (score 1):

```js
function replace(hash, el) {
    document.querySelector(`.topnav a.active`).classList.remove("active");
    el.classList.add("active");
}
```

```css
.topnav {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}
.topnav a {
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
  color: white;
  transition-duration: 200ms;
}
.topnav a:hover, .topnav:not(:has(a:hover)) a.active {
  background-color:green;
}
```

```html
<div class="topnav">
  <a class="active" href="#home" onclick="replace('home', this)">Home</a>
  <a href="#news" onclick="replace('news', this)">News</a>
  <a href="#contact" onclick="replace('contact', this)">Contact</a>
  <a href="#about" onclick="replace('about', this)">About</a>
</div>
```

Something like this? Your post was slightly vague but this is an idea of what you could do. You could potentially have some kind of server side script to add an active class to the initial active link or you could write some JavaScript to do it

CSS only solution just for fun:

```css
.topnav {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}
.topnav a {
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
  color: white;
  transition-duration: 200ms;
}
.topnav a:hover, .topnav:not(:has(a:hover)) :is(:not(:has(:target)) #home, :target) {
  background-color:green;
}
```

```html
<div class="topnav">
  <a id="home" href="#home">Home</a>
  <a id="news" href="#news">News</a>
  <a id="contact" href="#contact">Contact</a>
  <a id="about" href="#about">About</a>
</div>
```